# Setting text value based on only the selected spinner item

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have this code that I would like to use to update the cost of items based on the delivery zone selected in the spinner.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    delivery.setText(getCost(position));
    totalCost += Double.valueOf(delivery.getText().toString());
    total.setText(Double.toString(totalCost));
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    delivery.setText("0.00");
    totalCost -= Double.valueOf(delivery.getText().toString());
    total.setText(Double.toString(totalCost));

}
```

The value of totalCost should be the cost of the item plus tax plus the cost of delivery for the selected zone.
Now my problem is that

1. The first item is selectd by default on activity startup and it's cost used then the cost keeps incrementing when a user selects a different zone which of course has a different cost i.e if the cost of the item plus tax is 100 onload the totalCost becomes 150( cost for delivery to the first location is 50) when a user selects a different zone whose delivery cost is say 100 the total cost becomes 250 and not 200 as it adds directly to the initial value which composed the cost of the item plus the cost of delivery to the first zone and now the cost of delivery to the newly selected zones.

Is there any way I could rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*totalCost += replace with totalCost = ...* // problem is in this calculation*
```

*totalCost += adding the new value with old value*

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    delivery.setText(getCost(position));
//    totalCost += Double.valueOf(delivery.getText().toString());  change here
    totalCost = productPrice + Double.valueOf(delivery.getText().toString()); 
    total.setText(Double.toString(totalCost));
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    delivery.setText("0.00");
    totalCost -= Double.valueOf(delivery.getText().toString());
    total.setText(Double.toString(totalCost));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the basic value of the item - without delivery, say like this:

```
Double basePrice = //get it from your database
```

and then update the total price:

```
totalCost = basePrice + Double.valueOf(delivery.getText().toString());
```

instead of accumulating the price like you do with the `+=` operator.